# While migrating EF6 from SQL Server to Oracle. "Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time" getting this issue

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework-6

I have a requirement to migrate the Asp.Net with EF6 from SQL Server to an Oracle database.

When running `enable-migration`, I get this error:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Time

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: I have found the solution. We have decorate the respective property with timestamp type.